# NetBeans IDE not running project or file

Tags: java, netbeans

I have worked with NetBeans in the past and I wanted to work with it again, it was a long process of installing but I finally got it, and now that I am here it will not let me run my projects.
For one: It does not create a project with ant(at all)
For two: whenever I create a class it does not automatically close the name the class screen
For Three: When I right-click my class the run-file option is greyed out
For four: When I click run project the screen is stuck on "Initializing view, please wait..."

I really need to get this to work and I just can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong or if I am even doing something wrong.

Comment: You need to provide far more information than this, so update your question: [1] State the versions of NetBeans and JDK. All your problems may be dude to an incompatible combination. [2] Detail what you did to attempt to create an Ant project, and what didn't work. [3] Give a detailed example of not being able to run a class file. [4] Show any relevant content in the NetBeans log (**View > IDE Log**).

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the 4th problem:

You need to set the main class in your project.

- Right Click on the project folder, then click `properties`.
- Get to the tab `run`.
- Now type in the direction of your Main class you want to run:
  package + name of the class

example:
package name: com.mycompany.myproject
class name: MyClass.java
-> directory of Main Class: `com.mycompany.myproject.MyClass`

- click ok and try again

Worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions to try:

1. Run a clean and build
2. Right click the project --> properties --> ensure the correct main class is set
3. Upgrade and/or restart NetBeans

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, couldn't get it to work for the life of me, installed the latest version and everything went smoothly. I suggest not wasting time troubleshooting as I did, but instead updating to the latest version first.

Answer (score 0):

Write click on project->properties->run->Relative Url->Specify the file name that you want to run

After this the specified file will run by clicking the green run button given on the top.